# Java Table Rendered

Tags: java

I have a swing table with 4 columns. String, boolean(checkbox), String, Button. I pass a button to it and I get string of the button which I knew was going to happen. So I go about setting up a custom table renderer to make it render the button but I'm getting an exception and I'm not sure what it's trying to tell me.

This is my rendered class:

```
JtableButtonRendereer implements TableCellRenderer {
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    JButton button = (JButton) value;
    if (isSelected) {
        button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
        button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
        button.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
    }
    return button;

}
}
```

And this is what I'm using to set the renderer

```
imageTable.getColumn("TwitterFeed").setCellRenderer(new JtableButtonRendereer());
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Identifier not found
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumnIndex(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:282)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getColumn(JTable.java:2564)
    at javaapplication17.NewJFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:187)
    at javaapplication17.NewJFrame.access$000(NewJFrame.java:36)
    at javaapplication17.NewJFrame$1.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:60)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

The error is coming from the line I set the new renderer. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

From the stacktrace it seems there is no column with the identifier "TwitterFeed" in the table. Note that this is a case senstitive check.